# My responsive menu gets gliched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on my responsive menu that will be on desktop view a normal horizontal menu, but when the screen is smaller than 992px a hamburger style button will appear which will toggle a push-in side menu.

The problem i am facing is that the menu glitches when resizing the window aka switching between desktop and mobile view.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Menu</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
```

my css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

}
```

and my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mobile-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('closed');
    });

    $('.expander-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active-menu');

    });

});

$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    var screenWidth = $( window ).width();
    if(screenWidth < 992){
        $('.u').addClass('isMobile');

        $('#icon').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("open closed");
            if($( "#con" ).hasClass( "open" )){
                $('.gation').css('margin-left',"0");

            }
            else{
                $('.asdn').css('margin-left',"-70%");
            }
        });


    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean the menu 'glitches'?

Comment: The "desktop" menu wont show after i resize from mobile resolution, and vice versa, or the mobile menu button wont do anything on click, it buggs itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your JS, move everything you can to CSS. Instead of modifying margin left in JS do it in CSS, and whenever you toggle class `open` on `mr-mobile-icon`, toggle it also on `mr-navigation`. Your `$(window).on('load resize', ... );` is unnecessary. Just remove it, let CSS do everything for you.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .mr-navigation {
        // style
        margin-left: -70%;
    }
    .mr-navigation.opened {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$('#mr-mobile-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.mr-navigation').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand what you're trying to do here but the first issue I see is that you're adding a click event to mr-mobile-icon constantly while while the window is resized.  These click events don't erase existing click events, they stack.  After the window has resized, you might have hundreds of click events on mr-mobile-icon, all telling the browser to change css attributes.

You'll want to remove the click event assignment from the window resize and load event and just use the one you've already got in the document.ready.  If you scope the screenWidth variable to be globally-accessible, you can use it inside your click function.

Here's a basic example of what I'm suggesting, with your other code removed:

```
var screenWidth = $( window ).width();

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mr-mobile-icon').click(function(){
         if(screenWidth < 992) {
           // do whatever needs to happen for mobile
        } else {
            // do whatever needs to happen for desktop
        }
    });

});

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    screenWidth = $( window ).width();
});
```